# What is wrong with this way to move temporary variable out of function?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with following code where `Result` is a class with a `move constructor`:

```
Result&& GetResult(unsigned char* ptr)
{
    Result res = Result(ptr);
    return std::move(res);
}

Result ret = GetResult(ptr);
```

I know that the recommended way is to have return type `Result` and `return res;` and let compiler to call move constructor itself. But I want to understand what is going on in the case above with the lifetime of local variable `res`, because it seems to be "dead" at the time it is passed to `move constructor` in `Result ret = GetResult(ptr);`.
On the other hand `Result&& res = GetResult(ptr);` keeps it alive.

Comment: rvalue references are still references, so this has all the problems that returning a `Result&` would have. Just return by value and move semantics will kick in.

Comment: You can't a return a reference (of any kind) to local variable (or a temporary). It is undefined behavior.

Comment: The object `res` is destroyed right after the return statement is executed, *i.e.*, before the move constructor of `ret` starts running.

Comment: If you return by value, in this case no move should happen at all, but ReturnValueOptimization (i.e., `res` is directly constructed at a place allocated by the calling function).

Comment: Don't return by `move` you prevent the compiler from potentially eliding the move.